# How to implement reCAPTCHA V3 in salesforce lightning component?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to implement reCAPTCHA V3 in lightning component. Refering to https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3. I have done step 1 and 2 as mentioned here But I don't know how to implement step 3 (how to send the token to backend with the request and how to verify a user's response to a reCAPTCHA challenge from application's backend).

I created a visualforce page for frontend integration in which I have loaded the JavaScript api with my sitekey and called grecaptcha.execute when the page loads. Then added the visualforce page in lightning component using  tag.

---

```
<script>
  function onload()       
    {        
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {       
       grecaptcha.execute('my_sitekey', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {            
         //alert(token);
       });
      });  
   }
</script>

<body onLoad = "onload()">
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="html_element"></div>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can't be implemented. V3 use JS to catch mouse's movement. Because it is not visual, iframe's height should be 0, it can't get the mouse's movement. So, it's an unrealizable task.